# How To Search & Replace From a Word to another in The Same Line?

Tags: command-line, notepad++, regex, sed

Like I said,, I want to search each line, **from** a word at the beginning of the line, **To** another word at the end !

For Example, let's say that I've a text file, that contains these lines :-

```
1.RA.xm: Width="224" Height="40" Type>BX15
2.RA.xm: Width="235" Height="43" Type>BX23
3.RA.xm: Width="215" Height="51" Type>BX84
```

I want to search for the part from **xm** to **Type** in each line, and Replace with nothing

So, the result is going to be like this:-

```
1.RA.>BX15
2.RA.>BX23
3.RA.>BX84
```

It doesn't matter what tool I have to use for this.
But please If it possible, I prefer using a GUI App Regex (like NP++),
Or By using any command line tool (I've Cygwin & GNUWin on my system)

I'd be so grateful for anyone can help...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/xm.*Type//' file
```

That deletes from the first instance of `xm` to the last instance of `Type`
`.*` means zero or more ("*") of any character (".")

Comment: Both answers are right and so useful to me . I don't know how to accept both of them as the correct answers that solved my problem , 
but I was able to make them both as useful answers .
Thank you Bro for your help, I wish you all success in life :)

Comment: Hello again Bro... I'm facing another problem, and I need your help please. I want to use sed to search a text file for this **</Graph>**, and replace it with nothing. I've tried to find any solution for that slash problem, but none worked for me. I've tried to use this command `sed -e s:</Graph>:g "InPut.txt" > "OutPut.txt"` So, what's your suggestions in this case ? - Thanks -

Comment: The `s///` command need 3 delimiters, and you only gave 2: `sed 's:</Graph>::g'` -- search for "</Graph>" and replace with ""

Answer (score 1):

For Notepad++, use this find pattern:

```
xm.*?Type
```

and replace with nothing.

`.*?` matches everything between `xm` and the first instance of `Type` that follows on the same line. Check your settings to make sure that `.` does NOT match newline characters.

Comment: Thanks So Much Excellll, I really appreciate your help...

Answer (score 0):

This does the job:

- Find what: `(.*RA.xm:)(.*?)*?(Type>.*?)`
- Replace with: `\1>\4`